# best way to handle time validation for textbox

Tags: c#, validation, time

Hello my WinForm application has a textbox that will be used for a time value. I know how to load like the current time into the textbox, but say when a user enters a value, what is the best way to validate or format the number so I can attempt to Convert it to a `TimeDate` value?

Example: 
User enters something like `800` should be able to be converted to `8:00am` or `2354` should be `11:54pm`. Also if they enter an invalid time, like `9cdf83` or something, I need to check that this value is convertable to a time. If not, throw a warning. Is there a way to display a system clock to choose the time from like the `dateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like date and time which u want user to enter best is to use DateTimePicker bcoz n number of users will have n number of ideas to fill it. u can't go on checking each and every option.

Instead DateTimePicker will make user to enter through it only.

Comment: okay do you know of a good way to get this to show for a `datagridview` cell enter event so that it appears, the user clicks on the desired value, and the `dataTimePicker.Value` is entered into the clicked cell?

Answer (score 0):

you can place the textbox and a label beside it specifying the format like 8:00 AM and for validating it you can use custom validation and use a suitable regular expression as required for the validator and attach it to textbox.

But For conversion I thing you will have to code and check its validity.